# Outbound links when Analytics is blocked by browser

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

In Google Analytics Help there is following example https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1136920?hl=en

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" onclick="captureOutboundLink('http://www.example.com'); return false;">Check out example.com</a>

<script>
/**
* Function that captures a click on an outbound link in Analytics.
* This function takes a valid URL string as an argument, and uses that URL string
* as the event label. Setting the transport method to 'beacon' lets the hit be sent
* using 'navigator.sendBeacon' in browser that support it.
*/
var captureOutboundLink = function(url) {
   ga('send', 'event', 'outbound', 'click', url, {
     'transport': 'beacon',
     'hitCallback': function(){document.location = url;}
  });
}
</script>
```

The problem is that click action itself is stop working when Analytics is somehow blocked by browser or some extension. It's ok if click isn't captured in those situations but going to outbound location is obligate. How it can be done?

Answer (score 0):

you might check for `ga` object existence and wrap the navigation in `try ... catch` statement. Something like:

```
var captureOutboundLink = function(url) {
   if (window.ga) {
     try {
       ga('send', 'event', 'outbound', 'click', url, {
         'transport': 'beacon',
         'hitCallback': function(){document.location = url;}
       });
     } catch {
       document.location = url
     }
   } else {
     document.location = url
   }
}
```